# What are the semantics for dual-intuitionistic logic?

Tags: logic, kripke

Paraconsistent logic which modifies classical logic by rejecting the principle of explosion or *ex contradictione sequitur quodlibet* can be seen purely formally. The question remains as to how one interprets the logic - that is what is its semantics.

One broad class of paraconsistent logics are dual-intuitionistic logics. Now the standard semantics of intuitionisitic logic uses Kripke frames. Does one dualise here to get semantics for dual-intuitionistic logics?

**EDIT**

Priest, in his paper *Dualising intuitionistic negation* shows that dualising the truth condition for negation in the Kripke frame gives a paraconsistent logic which he calls a De Costa logic (it is stronger than Da Costa own logic - C-Omega). So, the semantics of De Costa logic has a Kripke possible world semantics but with negation dualised.

This implies that there is more than one way to dualise intuitionistic logic. I'm primarily interested in viewing intuitionistic logic as a heyting algebra in category theory, and standardly dualising that to get co-heyting algebras.

Answer (score 5):

Another insightful reference for the semantics of dual-intuitionistic logics is [Yaroslav Shramko](http://kdpu.edu.ua/shramko/yse.htm)'s paper on the "logic of scientific research" (Studia Logica 2005).

Just to add a brief comment on @TMF's answer, for the benefit of the author of the original question, it is worth noting that Priest's "Da Costa Logic" was indeed proposed as a fragment of Rauszer's "Brouwer-Heyting logic", extending the conjunction-disjunction fragment of classical/intuitionistic logic by adding an intuitionistic implication and a co-intuitionistic negation, but not the duals of the latter two connectives.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the "dualized" intuitionistic logics in the literature, e.g., Priest-da Costa and anti-intuitionistic, are fragments of Cecylia Rauszer's Heyting-Brouwer logic, in which all connectives---not merely negation---are given duals.  It's probably worth your time to review Rauszer's 1974 "Semi-Boolean Algebras and Their Application to Intuitionistic Logic with Dual Operations" and 1977 "Applications of Kripke Models to Heyting-Brouwer Logic."

The use of the prefix "co-" is a function of the use of the term "dual" and the latter is used in a variety of ways. Still, I suspect that whatever you intend by "co-Heyting algebra," a variety of pretenders to that title can be found implicitly in Rauszer.

Answer (score 2):

The paper H.P. Sankappanavar, "Heyting algebras with dual pseudocomplementation", published in
Pacific journal of Mathematics 117 (1985), 405–415, I believe, provides an algebraic semantics for what Priest calls as "Da Costa Logic".